# Is it true that $X$ and $Y$ gaussian and $\mathbb E[XY]=0\implies X$ and $Y$ independent?

Tags: probability

I was wondering if it is true that : $X$ and $Y$ gaussian and $\mathbb E[XY]=0\implies X$ and $Y$ independent ?

Comment: No, you need that they are jointly gaussian.

Answer (score 2):

no, this is false.

If $X$ and $Y$ are *jointly* Gaussian though, the their *covariance* is $0$, then they are independent.

So you need to add the jointly Gaussian assumption and a the fact that one of them has $0$ mean (in this case $E(XY)=Cov(XY)$)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what mean *jointly Gaussian* ?

Comment: it means that the joint distribution of the vector $(X,Y)$  is a two dimensional Gaussian distribution